# We can't find a user with that e-mail address in Laravel 5 authentication

Tags: php, email, laravel-5.3

Whenever I tried to reset my password in my Laravel project, they give me the error

`We can't find a user with that e-mail address`

I have change in `.env` file for sending mail from my project.

`.end` file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=shetshuvro@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

So for What else the problem occured?

Answer (score 1):

It happens in a case when you are trying to reset a password for a user through reset link but mistakenly you are entering a different (*unregistered*) email address.

It has nothing to do with **.env** configuration.

For reference have a look at the file:

> /resources/lang/en/passwords.php

Answer (score 0):

It's not any kind of functional problem of a project. It means there is no such a  user in your database table who have this email. So give an email of a user who is registered in your project or exists in your database table.